# How to log stderr from task executed asynchronously using uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

In my Flask app I allocate a ThreadPool before the first request and use the threads allocated here to execute tasks asynchronously

```
from app import app
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


@app.before_first_request
def initialize():
    app.pool = ThreadPool(10)
```

Sometime later...

```
app.pool.apply_async(exporter, args=(domains))
```

I am using a uWSGI backend for my webserver and this works fine except my `uwsgi` log in `/var/log/uwsgi/%n.log` only logs the `stdout` from threads executed from this pool. I am unable to see the `stderr`. I was wondering if this was possible using `uwsgi` logging capabilities or if I have to use a pluggable logger. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached a solution by just using the `error_callback` argument for `apply_async`.

I created a function:

```
def error_handler(e):
    traceback.print_exception(type(e), e, e.__traceback__)
```

And then execute the asynchronous task as follows:

`app.pool.apply_async(exporter, args=(domains), error_callback=error_hander)`

This returns the stderr to the main thread after it is done executing.